# Background property browser compatibility

Tags: css, safari, compatibility

I am using `background: url('../img/icon_drop.svg') no-repeat 25px 30px / 17px;` in one of my websites and it works very well in all browsers. Except Safari, unfortunately in Safari so written css is not recognised. I've already tried to find compatibility but i could not find any. Does anyone know is this supported by Safari?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Update your code like below.

```
body{
background: url('http://isc.stuorg.iastate.edu/wp-content/uploads/sample.jpg') no-repeat 25px 30px;
background-size:17px;
 }
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/7s0ogany/1/)

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, **Safari** doesn't understand the background size, so you have to do something like:

```
background: url('../img/icon_drop.svg') no-repeat;
background-size: 25px 30px / 17px
```